# Is $\exists x \in A ~:~ P(x)$ the same as $\exists x ~:~ x \in A \implies P(x)$

Tags: logic, quantifiers

If we wish to convert a statement of the form $\exists x \in A ~:~ P(x)$ into the form of an implication, would the correct conversion be

$$\exists x ~:~ x \in A \implies P(x)$$

Thanks

Comment: An $x$ is  missing in your formula:)

Comment: **NO**. $(∃x \in A)P(x)$ is the abbreviation for : $∃x(x \in A ∧ P(x))$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Could you please transform your comments into an answer?

Comment: Note that this *would* be the right conversion for a universal quantifier: "$\forall x\in A(P(x))$" is shorthand for "$\forall x(x\in A\implies P(x))$."

Answer (score 5):

NO.

$(∃x ∈ A)P(x)$ is the abbreviation for: $∃x \ (x∈A ∧ P(x))$ and this one is **not** equivalent to $∃x \ (x∈A \to P(x))$.

$∃x \ (x∈A ∧ P(x))$ is *false* if there are no elements in $A$ (i.e. when $A$ is empty) while in this case $∃x \ (x∈A \to P(x))$ is *true*.