# Is $\forall x \in U: f(x) \in V$ the same as $x \in U \implies f(x) \in V$?

Tags: logic, notation, definition

As the title says, do the following two statements have the same meaning? $$\forall x \in U: f(x) \in V \text{ (for all $x \in U$, $f(x) \in V$)}$$ $$x \in U \implies f(x) \in V \text{ ($x \in U$ implies that $f(x) \in V$)}$$

Comment: No, its not the same. The "such that" notation is the indication of a particular situation (in this case), but the "implication" notation is the indication of a general situation (in all cases).

Comment: The colon does not mean such that, it's supposed to mean that the part $\forall x \in U$ is applied to $f(x) \in V$. Another way to write this is $\forall x \in U (f(x) \in V)$. I think a more common way of writing this is $\forall x \in U, f(x) \in V$.

Comment: I never see the colon meaning a different thing than "such that" so I cant help you here.

Comment: If you want, you can just read the first statement as for all $x \in U, f(x) \in V$. The second statement remains the same. I'll edit the question to clarify this. Also, the question isn't about the notational use of the colon anyway.

Comment: See also the post [is $(\exists x \in A) Px$ the same as $\exists x (x \in A \to Px)$ ?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158643/is-exists-x-in-a-px-the-same-as-exists-x-x-in-a-implies-px) for the case with $\exists$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Restricted quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)#Equivalent_expressions):

> $(\forall x \in D)P(x)$ is equivalent to: $\forall x (x \in D \to P(x))$.

Thus, your formula: $∀x \in U : f(x) \in V$ is equivalent to:

> > $\forall x (x \in U \to f(x) \in V)$.